Using a custom case_when function in dplyr mutate
I've review many posts related to my question, but I cannot seem to figure out my issue.
I have a basic table that will have additional columns as collection (the NFL season) continues. I cannot get my function using a case_when based on the week to run without returning "! object 'WK1' not found"
My data after the second week.
NumCorrect <- data.frame(
  TEAM = c(stringr::str_c("team_", 1:5)),
  WK1 = c(11,12,11,12,13),
  WK2 = c(7,7,9,10,7)
)

My code.
# Defined variable at the top of the code that I change as the weeks are played.
curWEEK = 2

# Simplified version of my dplyr code at the step that won't work. 
correct_d <- mutate(AVG_16 = average16(curWEEK))


My function.
average16 <- function(x) {case_when(x == 1 ~ WK1,
                                    x == 2 ~ round(mean((WK1:WK2), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x == 3 ~ round(mean((WK1:WK3), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x %in% 4:7 ~ round(mean((WK1:WK4), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x %in% 8:11 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x %in% 12:14 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x == 15 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x == 16 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK16), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x == 17 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK17), na.rm=TRUE),1),
                                    x == 18 ~ round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK18), na.rm=TRUE),1)
                                    )}

I tried making R and chatGPT fight it out but the function just got more and more convoluted without a solution.
How can I use a function to find the average of only certain columns in a table that isn't complete and will have columns added to it?
I have tried many versions and am able to modify the code to leave all week columns (WK1 to WK18) with unplayed weeks as NA, but still received the 'Object not found' error.
Error everytime:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `AVG_16
  = average16(curWEEK)`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! Failed to evaluate
  the right-hand side of
  formula 1.
Caused by error:
! object 'WK1' not found

I also attempted this:
average16 <- function(x) {if(x == 1) {WK1}
                          if(x == 2) {round(mean((WK1:WK2), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x == 3) {round(mean((WK1:WK3), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x %in% 4:7)   {round(mean((WK1:WK4), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x %in% 8:11)  {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x %in% 12:14) {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x == 15) {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x == 16) {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK16), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x == 17) {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK17), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          if(x == 18) {round(mean(c(WK1:WK4,WK8,WK12,WK15:WK18), na.rm=TRUE),1)}
                          }


Do you really want to ignore the values of weeks 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, and 14?  Maybe you should try to explain what you want.

your only input is curWEEK, WEEK1 is not provided nor initiated so it's not found. you might want to provide the df as an input and have the mutate() call inside of the function

@MichaelDewar, yes, I am looking to create an average for weeks that only include a full 16 games (hence average16). The other weeks of the NFL season include "bye" weeks for teams so comparing an average correct in a week with less than 16 would undercut the meaning of the statistic.

@moodymudskipper the curWEEK is defined outside of the data step so I can update it easily as the weeks progress. WK1 is a column in the df along with more that will be added after every week up to week 18. I included a simplified version of my data at the top of my question. I edited it to work better.

If you're using dplyr, then maybe a very different method might achieve your goal.
You can use a character vector to specify the columns that you want to take the mean of, if they exist.  If they don't exist, then any_of will silently ignore them.
library(tidyverse)
NumCorrect <- data.frame(
    TEAM = LETTERS[1:5],
    WK1 = c(11,12,11,12,13),
    WK2 = c(7,7,9,10,7)
)

cols_to_avg <- paste0("WK", c(1:4, 8, 12, 15:18))

NumCorrect |> 
    rowwise() |> 
    mutate(avg16 = round(mean(c_across(any_of(cols_to_avg))),1)) |> 
    ungroup()


I knew I was overthinking it. This method also allows me to edit the weeks to include because they're not always consistent between NFL seasons. Massive thank you for taking care of a problem that has plagued me for years.
